# How do I call data from API array to draw a dynamic billboard on Cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have the following information on the API, I would like to extract all latitude and longitude to plot many billboard markings on cesium.

```
[

{"description": "aaa", "address": "bbb", "latitude": "1.34791838898824", "longitude": "103.8487501254"},
{"description": "ddd", "address": "ccc", "latitude": "1.37026158388488", "longitude": "103.839467898898"},
....
```

]

How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Let say that you are storing data in a variable called data

```
var data = [

{"description": "aaa", "address": "bbb", "latitude": "1.34791838898824", "longitude": "103.8487501254"},
{"description": "ddd", "address": "ccc", "latitude": "1.37026158388488", "longitude": "103.839467898898"}]
```

To extract only one property from this table you can use map function as follow :

```
var extractedLatitudes = data.map(t => t.latitude);
```